# Expresso Store Product Tag returns empty - including all template HTML

Tags: expresso-store

Silly question here I'm sure -- created a new channel for products on a pre-existing EE/Expresso Store install. I'm using code that easily displays products for the old channels, but seems to be breaking on this new template. Here's the template's tags --

`{exp:channel:entries channel="mounts" limit="1" dynamic="no"}
 {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" return="/ordnance/store-checkout"}`

Any items placed in between the product tag and its closer is omitted from the resulting page. I was thinking that maybe there was a breakdown from the prior page sending the proper entry_id, but if I move the product tag down further in the code (to say, wrap only the "Buy Now" button), the proper product and associated fields are in fact displayed on the page.

So, essentially, the product tag is encountering an error and causing all wrapped content to not be displayed, as well as the modifiers included there.

A couple of notes that might help: 1) this is the first channel to be displayed on this site under a new template group. In other words, all other products/channels were displayed at

> xxxx.com/firearms/all-old-product-channels/product-page

And this new channel is being displayed at

> xxxx.com/ordnance/new-channel-/product-page

& 2) That's the reason I through the `dynamic="no"` into the entries tag.

Sorry for the poorly formed question, but it's my first here. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I first stated, I'm sure this was a silly question. Dealt with the wonderful Devs of the Expresso Store who quickly were able to step through a few debugging items only to find the culprit:

I didn't have a price set for the product.

By simply setting the price 0.01 (or more), the Expresso Store happily displayed the full contents of the entry, and everything is working as expected. I hope my idiocy helps someone in the future!